# Keeping user logged in, in a react flux app?

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, flux, session-storage

I am working on a react-flux app where I am using sessionStorage to keep a user logged in by checking if email and auth token are available in sessionStorage. If they are available and time since login is less than 15 minutes, I trigger off a flux action to log the user in. I also have another function that irrespective logs the user out after 15 minutes by clearing out the sessionStorage.

It works fine, until I refresh the page. At this point, the setInterval function that logs the user out after 15 minutes, resets itself.

Here's the code to make sense of what I am referring to:

In my parent component I have the following functions that I call inside componentDidMount function.

```
checkSession: function() {
    if (!_.isNull(window.localStorage)) {
      var currentTimeStamp = Date.parse(new Date());
      var logInStamp = window.sessionStorage.time;
      var difference = currentTimeStamp - logInStamp;

      if (Math.floor((difference / 1000) / 60) < 15) {
        var data = {
          email: window.sessionStorage.email,
          scheduler_slug: window.sessionStorage.slug
        };
        ActionCreator.loginUser(data);
      }
    }
  },

  logOut: function() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn === true) {
      window.sessionStorage.clear();
      ActionCreator.logOutUser();
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    Store.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    this.checkSession();
    setInterval(this.logOut, 900000);
  }
```

I am setting the key values for sessionStorage on success of my ajax call for creating a session. In subsequent api calls, i send back the token i received in response from the first call in my response header for authentication.

My question is 2 fold:

1) Is my current approach enough to maintain user session? Would using cookies be better?

2) If my current approach is fine, then I need to figure out a way to prevent timer from resetting on page refresh which I thought would be an easy fix but everything I am seeing involves using cookies. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is very subjective. If this approach works for you, that is ok. Cookies are also a good option for this, it just depends. You mention that you have some troubles using your current approach (mostly on page refresh). A cookie could help, but isn't some silver bullet either. Choose wisely what fits your app the best (think about if you ever want your server calls to be called from libraries etc, which might introduce more annoyances when using cookies.
2. Since you already store something in the `sessionStorage`, you can also choose to store the data simply in localStorage. This will ensure it stays the same, and since the time is saved as well you're basically providing your own session storage, that survives a refresh.

A side note, `sessionStorage` shouldn't reset itself on a refresh, it lives in a tab-context. So if you open a new tab you do get a new session, if you refresh you should be having the same storage. Depending on your app you might want to take a look if you somewhere replace the data, or if the refresh happens in a different tab.